# What is the java validated RegExp pattern for yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm?

Tags: java, android, regex, date, datetime

I am trying to validate a string in android and I can't seem to find it in the internet.  And no,  I don't know how to make my own regexp sorry. T_T

Also, I can't use simpleDateFormat or other objects. I need the regexp for a validation int the xml file of a view I need to use.

I need to validate the String, and please don't worry about the random dates and feb29 clauses. I just need to validate the Text pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the date 2000-01-01 00:00 to 2100-12-31 23:59 with:

```
\A(?:2100|20[0-9]{2})-(?:0?2-(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[469]|11)-(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[13578]|1[02])-(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))[ \t]+(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])[:.][0-5]?[0-9]\b
```

Comment: You're the wizard I was waiting for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use regex to validate dates, consider the case of 29 Feb and a random year, Use `SimpleDateFormat` instead

Comment: but.. but whyyy.. T_T

Comment: @John elaborate your comment please

Comment: I actually just need the user to type the date and then the custom view will use the regex to validate the data. I don't know, I just feel it can be done, the regex could be created by a wizard. If only I knew how to create my own regexs

Comment: You can create regex for text pattern, but date has this leap year concept, can you validate it with regex ? (give it a thought)

Comment: Oh wait, I just need to validate the text pattern, and THEN I can use a SimpleDateFormat to validate the date then then show a popup that the date is nonexistent. Would that be alright?

Comment: Simply use `SimpleDateFormat` to validate Date

Comment: Yes but I need the user to input the date in a specific format

Comment: Told you there'll be a wizard to save me.